# Visual Studio 2017 Installer Project Issue - Unable to Update Dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, setup-project

We have a solution in which 57 projects are included. When we add a new installer project, after adding the project output or doing some changes like Setup Title, Icon etc, after rebuilding this installer project , it gives the error like Unable to update the dependencies of project. Cleaning,Rebuilding the solution did not help in this. I have to delete and recreate the setup project again and again. I go through some links, there I found a similar problem and fix in this link provided by microsoft. Here is the link : https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2286556/fix-error-message-when-you-build-a-visual-studio-2010-setup-project-un 
But when I try to download this fix, it is not available. Please help us in this , as it is very annoying and we have to again and again recreating the setup project.
Visual Studio 2017 Installer Project Extension Version - 0.8.8
Visual Studio 2017 15.9
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Installer project deprecated after VS 2010, it is not supported in Later version of VS. So you better try alternate Setup Project like `InstallShield`. Try to create a project using it and let me know the status.

Comment: If Installer Project is deprecated , why Microsoft is releasing and supporting the extension for latest visual studio version, like if you see the installer project extension version for vs 2017, it starts from 0.8 and now it is 0.8.8. So , if it is deprecated, why they are still working on this.

Comment: I am not sure of the update version you are specifying here. if you want to work with installer project then use VS 2010 instead 2017 or go for 3rd party installer project as i said earlier.